# Makefile for springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, makefile

I have a spring boot application.I am running it inside a vagrant box(centos).I use intelliJ IDEA.

I have created a Makefile and I am trying to run this application.

I have never worked with Makefile hence I am not confident about it.
Hence the question might seem easy for some of you.I tried to do a bit of research but I could not achieve any success in it.

My Makefile contains:-

install-mvn:
    mvn :install

I opened a terminal and went to the location where my Makefile is located and then issue the 'make' command to run the application.

I get the error as below:-

```
[vagrant@localhost src]$ make
mvn :install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]     ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

### [INFO]

```
[INFO] Total time: 0.578s

[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 14 17:24:31 IST 2017

[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/22M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Could not find goal '' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-      install-plugin:2.3.1 among available goals install, install-file, help -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException

make: *** [install-mvn] Error 1
```

I did not understand the error.Can any of you guide me with this?I would like to know what is being expected and what should the Makefile contain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `:` in `:install`.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I removed it.Now the Makefile contains' install-mvn: mvn install'. My  previous error is resolved. But I got something new this time as follows:-  [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/vagrant/Share/springbootservice/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Comment: You should invoke this from the `springbootservice` directory which is the directory that contains your `pom.xml`. Wy are you adding additional complexity of a Makefile?

Comment: What is the reason for the makefile requirement?  If you use start.spring.io to build an example app, you will get a maven wrapper that will download and install maven for you on "most" platforms.

Comment: @DaShaun The project uses some applications that are in different languages/technologies.For instance Golang,c#,Java to mention a few.Hence maven wrapper will not be that helpful.The idea is to put all the configurations of various languages/technologies in a single Makefile.Thanks for spending time on my question. :)

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thanks the solution you provided seems to work well.Thanks for spending time in reading and answering my question. :)